Number of transitions into and out of state j in continuous-time Markov chain?
In Introdution to  Probability Models, it says that $$v_jP_j=\sum_{k\ne j}q_{kj}P_k, \text{ all states j }$$ and $$\sum_jP_j=1$$ have the interpretation that in any interval (0,t), the number of transitions into state $j$ must equal to within 1 the number of transitions out of state $j$. By intuition I can understand that the rates should be equal, but I don't know why the bolden statement is true.
I thought that if by time t the process stays in state j, then #of transitions into will be one less; if by time t the process is not in state j, then # of transitions into and out of should be equal. But how can this thought be connected with these two equations? So I guess I was wrong, but I wonder the correct answer and why I was wrong.
